# bash IF statement doesn't work - getting error

Tags: bash

i'm trying write simple IF statement in bash, but no mater what i try i allway get error, that shouldn't rise at all, can someone please take a look at my code and tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Checking..."
echo
if [ -f /var/www/git/repos/last_change.txt ];
    then
    echo "/var/www/git/repos/last_change.txt exists."
        cd /var/www &&
        git fetch --all &&
        git reset --hard origin/develop &&
        rm -f "/var/www/git/repos/last_change.txt"

fi;
echo
echo "...done."
```

I allways get error:

```
root@machine:/var/www/git/repos# sh check.sh
Checking...
: not found: 3: check.sh: echo
check.sh: 12: check.sh: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

Everything seems to be ok, right?

I am glad for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by error description, most likely your file uses DOS newlines (CRLF). `sh` expects UNIX newlines (LF). Convert your file with `dos2unix your_file_name.sh`.

Comment: Thanks that was the issue.